# Как в контроллере поймать событие окончания ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-controller, scope, ng-repeat

Как в контроллере поймать событие окончания `ng-repeat`?
Есть вот такой HTML код:

```
<input type='text' ng-model="searchTel.id_device_type">
 <div ng-repeat="tel in tel_list | filter:aaaa:tel">
         <div class="item">
             <img src="images/{{tel.url_img_tel}}" class="img-content">
                 <div class="item-content">
                    <p >{{tel.code_tel}}</p>
                    <p >{{tel.name_tel}}</p>
                 </div>
         </div>
    </div>
```

в контроллере

```
$scope.aaaa=function(tel)
    {
        if($scope.searchTel.id_device_type==0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
        if(tel.id_device_type==$scope.searchTel.id_device_type)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Пробовал:

```
$scope.$on('ngRepeatFinished', function(ngRepeatFinishedEvent) {
    console.log(ngRepeatFinishedEvent);
});
```

Не ловится.

Comment: Может проверить через '$last'

Comment: а зачем??? обычно это нет нужды делать

Comment: @Grundy я отфильтровал список, но мне нужно показывать его не сразу, а постепенно, например по 20 записей. Первоначально, все скрыты. По окончанию я буду показывать эти 20, по нажатии кнопки "показать еще" будут показываться следующие 20 не скрывая эти и тд

Comment: тогда тебе не нужно это событие, тебе нужен фильтр `limitTo` - которому ты будешь задавать сколько именно надо показать сейчас